# 3 way switch lighting 2 bulbs with independent on/off option

Tags: electrical, lighting, light, multiway-switch

I have the following set-up

[image: current setup]

I would like to be able to turn both on/off at the same time like they are doing now, and also controller each one separately, add another switch on each side that turns on/off only the light on it's side. Is this possible? How would I need to wire it?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Before even thinking about an answer, I must point out that your current setup contains a code violation: the current in C3 is balanced only by the current in C4. This is not allowed. The circuit requires a 4-wire cable between the lights.

Comment: First you must completely define what you want all four switches to do in all circumstances. When you flip a new switch, do you want its light to no longer respond to the three-way switches? If so, should it be on or off? If one light is on and one is off, and someone flips one of the three-ways, what should happen? If one light is on and one is off, what do you have to do to get them both on?

Comment: @ruskes this was found on the Internet. I've seen it before. The two cables C3/C4 are a code violation.  That's how I remember it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica you can not even trust internet

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question? Is replacing wiring an option for that matter?

Comment: Of course if Amin David got the diagram off the internet then it may be an inaccurate depiction of what he actually has. There might already be 14/4 between the lights. Or C1 and C2 might go to one light, with a 14/2 tying the other light in parallel. Querent has to examine all the wiring to be sure. Hope he responds to Eel's request.

Comment: I'm not from the USA. We really don't have codes or rulings or guides that we must follow. Here there are no home inspections or anything of that sort. Of course I would like for it to be as safe as possible but my house is not gonna get inspected by an electrician. @A.I.Breveleri

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I would like to have 4 light switches. 2 on each side. One on each side are three way and control both. The other ones only control the light on it's side. Optimally I want the switch that controls only one light to be prioritized over the three way. So if one light is on and the other is off when I flick either 3way switch the one that was off turns on and viceversa. But beggars can't be choosers so I'm happy with witchever wiring let's me get 3 ways switch's with independence. I'm currently remodeling that part of the house so I have basically all control over the wiring :)

Comment: Vote to re-open. What Amin David wants to do is unusual (and once he's done it he'll probably want to change it), but his intention and requirements are perfectly clear. He needs to control both lights independently from either switch box location.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri -- aye, VTROing based on the OP's comment that they can install whatever new wiring is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circuit does what querent says he wants:

[image: it can be done]

**Theory of Operation**

Switch S1 energizes one of the travelers in cable C1. Switch S3 reverses the effect of S1, producing a pair of travelers at its T2 terminals that is controlled by S1 and S3. These travelers are branched and fed to switch S4, and via cable C2 to switch S2.

Switch S4 then selects one of these T2 travelers, and connects it via cable C3 to lamp L2. Thus the state of L2 changes whenever any of S1, S3, or S4 is thrown.

Switch S2 also selects one of the T2 travelers, and connects it via cable C4 to lamp L1. Thus the state of L1 changes whenever any of S1, S3, or S2 is thrown.

The neutral return current from lamp L1 must flow through cable C2 and back through cable C1, in order to balance the current drawn by L1 through the travelers. The remainder of the neutral connections are obvious and natural.

As usual in a wiring diagram of any complexity, the safety grounds have been omitted.

However, the ground wires in cable C1 and C2 are not only redundant, but if connected at both ends, will form an inductive loop which may be energized by nearby conductors. Only one of these ground wires should be connected; the other should be capped.

**User Guide**

Switches S1 and S3 are called the "global" switches. They constitute a standard three-way circuit. Throwing either one will change the state of both lamps.

Switches S2 and S4 are the "local" switches. Switch S2 changes the state of lamp L1 relative to the three-way setting. Similarly, switch S4 changes the state of lamp L2 relative to the three-way setting.

It is always possible to control both lamps independently from either switch box location.

The general rule is: Use the closest local switch to set the lamps to either different states, or to the same state. Then use the global switch to select one of the two remaining possibilities.

Another approach is: Use the closest global switch to set the farthest lamp to the desired state, then if necessary use the local switch to set the closet lamp to the desired state.

Answer (score 1):

I hate smart switches and I will not have them in my house, but in this case I am going to wholly endorse their installation and use.

Comment: Quite agree, smart switches are the only way to solve some problems, and this is one of them.

Comment: Thank you. Im not familiar with them but I will do some digging.